# Como corrigir fonte serrilhada no chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Estou com um problema no Google Chrome. Não sei se é o CSS, mas as fontes declaradas no CSS estão ficando serrilhadas principalmente no Chrome. Já tentei as seguintes propriedades para diminuir o serrilhamento (anti-alising):

```
-webkit-font-smoothing;
font-smooth;
text-stroke;
text-shadow;
```

O site que está com este problema é [este](http://www.framepro.com.br/colorimetria.html).

Comment: Aqui está normal e estou usando Firefox.

Comment: @Patrick, esqueci de acrescentar, o problema é no chrome =/ obrigado.

Comment: Esse problema tinha sido corrigido, vai entender o que se passa no navegador do Google. Uma alternativa é você usar fontes em `svg`.

Comment: Poste um exemplo que não seja um link (use o [stacksnippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) para isto). Links online costumam ser editados e assim não poderá ser visto o problema.

Comment: Conseguir resolver com ClearType que pode ser visto aqui: http://www.ilista.com.br/blog/136-como-resolver-o-problema-de-fontes-serrilhadas-no-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este comportamento foi corrigido no Chrome 37. Para simular um resultado comparável ao antialias, você pode utilizar text-shadow, como no exemplo a seguir:

```css
.teste
{
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
}

.teste.antialias{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    }
```

```html
<span class='teste'>Alias</span><br>
(pre-Chrome 37)<br/>
<br/>
<span class='teste antialias'>Antialias</span>
```

Fonte: [How to apply font anti-alias effects in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864742/how-to-apply-font-anti-alias-effects-in-css), Stack Overflow (em inglês)